# How to get hold of the editor of the current line being debugged in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

I would like to get the IEditorPart that the debugger is currently inside.

I cannot rely on the active editor for the workbench because this is not necessarily up-to-date, even though it is visible on screen. See me other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9348767/101642).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alan