# how to create an eclipse plugin to auto create read/ writeExternal methods of existing class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, externalizable

How to create eclipse plugin to auto create the serialization code read/writeExternal on existing code java classes?

Steps needed get the class from active tab (and or info on class field info like one in outline window) and generate code for each field, maybe using reflection will also help.

Comment: I was wondering the same, all I need is current java class metadata like one in Outline window and it can be done, or just a class that is opened in current tab...

Comment: Look at the Eclipse JDT [AST Parser](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: yep, nice info also found this source code for hashcodeEquals from eclipse: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.1/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/GenerateHashCodeEqualsOperation.java

Comment: Is it similar to eclipse `generate getters and setters` ?

Comment: yes, this code is similar to hashcode and equals and generate getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to build upon `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.GenerateMethodAbstractAction`
that is used by eclipse to implement [`GenerateToStringAction`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.1/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/actions/GenerateToStringAction.java) and [`GeneateHashCodeEqualsAction`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.1/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/actions/GenerateHashCodeEqualsAction.java).

Basically:

1. Build a basic sub-class of `GenerateMethodAbstractAction`
2. Implement logic that enumerates all the fields / properties etc. you want to process in `generateCandidates()`. You also need to decide if you recurse into superclass or not.
3. Implement logic that generates `MethodDeclaration`s for readExternal/writeExternal methods using data collected in step 2.
4. Wrap generated `MethodDeclaration`s into an `IWorkspaceRunnable` that applies them as edits (see [`GenerateToStringOperation`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.1/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/codemanipulation/tostringgeneration/GenerateToStringOperation.java)) and return it from `createOperation(...)`.
5. Register your new action to "Source" menu so it can be used

The code required is rather long and involved so it's better to follow the two existing action classes for guidance.

If you choose to put it somewhere else than "Source" menu, you can discover the active editor with

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor()
```

See also:

- [How to extend the source menu in Eclipse? (or: What is its locationURI?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113380/how-to-extend-the-source-menu-in-eclipse-or-what-is-its-locationuri)
- [How to get "active editor" in Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348767/how-to-get-active-editor-in-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: will checkout this, sounds like a plan